# CSS Child Selector

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I understand the difference between child and descendants just fine. I am having an issue with the child selector however. Perhaps I am not understanding something correctly. Take the following HTML as an example. This is a 3 tier navigation menu.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Based on my understanding of the child ( > ) selector in css, the following would be true:

```css
#nav {}
#nav ul.menu {}
#nav ul.menu > li {} /* main navigation items only */
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu li {} /* the 2nd tier only */
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {} /* the 3rd tier only */
```

This does not seem to be the case however. The css for the 2nd tier is being applied to the 3rd tier as well. And only with an `!important` declaration am I able to overwrite the 2nd tier within the last css definition.

Make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
nav ul.menu > li {} /* main navigation items only */
```

**correct**

```css
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu li {} /* the 2nd tier only */
```

**wrong** - You are selecting the `ul.menu` child `li` which has child `ul.sub-menu`, all the `li` elements under it.

If you want to restrict it to that level only, use this:

```css
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {}
```

The last one

```css
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {}
```

should work fine as long as you keep it in 3 tiers only.

Comment: A small oversight on my part. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris no problem :). At least you have the luxury of using the `>` child selector... still stuck on working on sites which support IE6 myself :(

Answer (score 1):

```
#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu li {}
```

will apply to 2 tier and beyond.

```
#nav > ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {}
```

would apply to 2nd tier only...

Answer (score 1):

`#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu li {}` // second tier

The last `ul.sub-menu li` selector selects both the *child* `li` elements from the 2nd tier and the *decendant* `li` within the 3rd tier.

`#nav ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu > li {}` // might force it to restrict to the second tier

Also, according to http://www.evotech.net/blog/2008/05/browser-css-selector-support/ the support for 'E > F' selectors is a little buggy in IE6, which may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Yea, I gave up coding for IE6 a long time ago. Supporting it is enabling it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, so worse than I expected ;)